# Can airplane mode provide a "free" I.P. masking service?

Tags: ip

My email service always logs the I.P. address of the device from which the email account was accessed(or an unsuccessful login attempt was made) for security reasons.

While going through the list once, I found that I had quite a few *different* I.P. addresses on that list, *most* of which were successful logins.

After some thinking, I remembered that I have been putting my phone on airplane mode quite often(which I still do, due to the internet connection dropping quite often at my home). I thought that this process was changing my I.P. address.

So, right now I checked for it again, and found that the last 2 octets of the IPv4 address changed everytime I switched ON(and then OFF) the airplane mode.

What is more interesting is the fact that the location of the device(checked on some online sites) was found to be oscillating between my city and a neighbouring [satellite city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_city).

So, my question is that, could this method, if used multiple times a day, act as a "free" I.P. masking service?

Comment: [**Original Author**] Also Google considers [resetting the last octet](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en) of the IPv4 address as IP "Masking".

Comment: Changing your IP is in no way, shape or form, a "VPN".

Comment: Changing your IP to a new IP while you surf is in no way a form of anonymisation of stored IP data for analytics (as per the google link you shared) nor does it mask your working IP while you surf. You do not appear to understand what IP Masking is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airplane mode disconnects you from the cellular network. When you turn it off, you reconnect to the network and get a new IP. That's it. You are using the same network, the same ISP, the same IP range, and the same general geographic location.

So, we can reduce your question to "can changing the IP from your ISP multiple times a day be the same as a VPN?" -- **no, because a VPN does far, far more than just changing your IP** and even as a proxy, a VPN does more to obscure where your device is connecting from.

Can it make it more difficult for the sites you connect with to identify your device? No, not really, because you are broadcasting a ton of other info when you connect to sites. Web admins know that devices change their IP all the time, so they rely on other data.

Can this method work to defeat IP-tracking processes? Sure. In highly specific circumstances.